# Limiting the Size of Apache HTTPD Memory Footprint

Tags: centos, memory, apache-httpd

I have a web server running Cent OS 5 with Apache. I have over 1GB of Ram and the MaxSpareServers set to 15. This would be fine under most situations, but for some reason my httpd processes are ballooning to over 150 mb a piece. I was googling around and saw a program called GTop and tried that, but I couldn't find any good tutorials on how to install it. Are there any simple ways to accomplish this?

Am I headed in the right direction or is there a better way to solve this problem?

Comment: First, establish whether it is a problem. Where does that 150MB figure come from? Is that the resident set (in which case it's a lot if each process is serving a single concurrent request, but not if it has 10000 threads), or the total mapped memory (which could be reasonable if you have many modules and opened data files)?

Comment: It may be worth reading [Apache performance tuning](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/perf-tuning.html)

Answer (score 2):

The 150MB is not apiece. It's almost certainly mostly shared. What you're saying doesn't suggest a problem.

Answer (score 1):

What do you serve using Apache ? Unloading some un-used modules could help bring down memory usage. Also the application you're serving could be leaking/using a lot of memory. Also try decreasing values of MaxClients and KeepAliveTimeout.